# SQLBolt.com - Alternative Answer to Lesson 8, Q2

Tags: sql, sql-null

I have an alternative answer to the 2nd question from Lesson 8 from https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_with_nulls

> Find the names of the buildings that hold no employees

My attempt is:
`SELECT building_name FROM buildings WHERE building_name NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT(building) FROM employees);`

It's not returning my answer as correct and prefers the answer `SELECT building_name FROM buildings LEFT JOIN employees ON building_name = building WHERE name IS NULL`

Please tell me if I've made a mistake. I didn't think that a join was needed here. Thanks

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's _set quantifier_, and applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT building FROM...`, to make code clearer.

Comment: Thank you. This also worked ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not made a "mistake".  But you query still has two issues.

First, `select distinct` is totally unnecessary.  `IN`/`NOT IN` take care of that -- they ignore duplicates.

More importantly, `NOT IN` does not work as most people expect with `NULL` values -- if any value in the subquery is `NULL` then no results are returned *at all*.  If the `employees` table has no `NULL` values in `building` then your version should work as intended.

For this reason, I strongly recommend that you always use `NOT EXISTS` with a subquery:

```
SELECT b.building_name
FROM buildings b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM employees e
                  WHERE b.building_name = e.building
                 );
```

The `LEFT JOIN` version is functionally equivalent to this version.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Just the amendment needed `SELECT b.building_name
FROM buildings b etc...`